# JVM Failed to start while installing java

Tags: java, eclipse, jdk, jre, jvm

I installed java, and then realized that it was the wrong version, so I tried reinstall Java, but mid installation it said "JVM Failed to start". I tried to install JDK 1.8.0_221. Any help would be great.

Comment: What version of Java were you installing? And where did you get it from?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: I edited the question so it would be more clear. I had jdk12.0.something and I tried to install jdk1.8.0_221. Also, any other java application wouldn't work and throw out this error. Edit: I just installed java 1.8.0_221 again. The folders in C:/Program Files/Java are just as I remember they were, and I found jvm.dll.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. I installed java, and it gave an error. Then, I changed _JAVA_HOME to
-Xmx2g. That worked. Thanks for the help!